# Problema con javascript, no detecta función

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo un problema con el siguiente código javascript

```
 function mostrar(block){
    document.getElementById(block).style.display='block';
    };
```

Resulta que no detecta el id del bloque que le estoy pasando

```
<li><button class="dropbtn" onclick='mostrar(block1)'>La Cámara   &raquo</button>
```

Donde block1 es:

```
<ul id="block1" class="dropdown-content">
```

Podríais ayudarme? Gracias!

Comment: Perdón, se me recargó al español que estaba preguntando en el de inglés, arreglé el problema este que me pasaron otro foro y era por un problema de rutas, pero ahora me sale otro error que estoy bastante confuso

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
[Learn More]    es el error y en el código html está puesto así     <ul id="block1" class="dropdown-content">   y en el js        function mostrar(block){
 document.getElementById(block).style.display='block';
};

Comment: Haría falta ver más código. Edita la pregunta para cambiarla por el nuevo error o bórrala y crea otra nueva.

Comment: Ya está solucionado, en block1 faltan las dobles comillas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fíjate en la línea `onclick='mostrar(block1)'`, estás enviando `block1` como si fuese una variable, pero en realidad lo que quieres mandar es un string, por lo tanto la solución sería:

```
... onclick="mostrar('block1')"
```

Comment: a mi me funciono asi    onclick='mostrar("block1")'

Comment: Da lo mismo, simplemente intercambiaste comillas.

Answer (score 0):

Faltan las dobles comillas en block1 en la llamada a onclick

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, por favor revisa [answer].